# How do I change the default overflow size in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, default, tmp

Google is failing me,

It appears in some systems it's located in a (script)file called mountoverflowtmp
under /etc/init.d/

However it doesn't appear to be there in Ubuntu, and I'm not having any luck finding it anywhere on Ubuntu 12.04.

Where can I configure it?

I'd like to change the default from the relatively useless 1MB size to something like 256MB.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://blog.cone.be/2009/08/31/overflow-tmpfs-on-tmp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task has been converted to an upstart job in Ubuntu, so the file you are looking for is /etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf.